# Don't include borderline cases in audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

The way the audit system works is basically fine: You can't mindlessly click the buttons to grind the queues, because if you do, you'll be banned sooner or later.

What I don't agree on is offering borderline situations for audit cases. I personally failed the audit on https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/8708565, because in my opinion the second part attempts to answer the question. In reality the answer was downvoted **marginally** to -1 and has only 2 comments, one discussing the technical aspect and one discussing the quality of the answer. 
The answer can be fine after some minor improvements.

I personally think the audit should deal with cases that are clearly good or clearly bad, the linked answer is -in my opinion- open for debate and shoudn't have been deleted so easily.

Edit: While the linked 'duplicate' is helpful in improving my review-skills, it's not about borderline audit cases.

Comment: How will the system identify borderline cases?

Comment: A positive score of over 5 or a negative score of less than -5 for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Audits are *picked automatically*, and the criteria are designed to select for what appear to be cut and dry cases.

But like all things automated, that can sometimes go wrong. What you *think* is a borderline case, the system thought was cut and dry, because it matched objective criteria (such as only upvotes and no edits, or only spam flags and downvotes, etc.).

If you come across an audit that you think is borderline, you need to go and *teach the system it is borderline*. Downvote it if you think it should not have been upvoted so much. Vote to close it if you think it is off-topic. That then gives the system a signal that the post was not so uncontroversial as it thought and stop using it as an audit.

In your specific case, the post was [deleted from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8422869) with just one Looks Good vote, and 6 deletion votes; the system thus thought it a good candidate. For deleted posts it is harder to 'teach' the system; flagging it for moderator attention or bringing it up on meta is then your only option.

Since this is a 'partial' answer (it is not cut and dry, there is a *bit* of an answer in there), I've undeleted and re-deleted it to clear it from audit duties, and lifted your review ban.

Comment: Well the answer was deleted so I can't teach the system anymore. This failed audit banned me for a month, so I won't be doing much reviewing soon anyway :(

Comment: @MeanGreen: but that means this wasn't your first failed audit. :-) I've lifted  your ban as this one was indeed not clear; it has been used 3 times and all three times the reviewer failed the audit.

Comment: @MeanGreen: [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) strikes again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters greatly appreciated! I'm still learning :)